# Named entity recognition(NER) on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

I want to train a NER model using Automl GCP. I annotate the data and upload it in the bucket.

By clicking to create the dataset, it seem that tha Automl service does not have the enough permission to read from the bucket. I check in the bucket parameters if I there is an option to give the permission to all APIs but I did not find.

Here is the error that I get. How I can grant the permission in this case ?

Not that I have the owner permission of the project.
I tried to create another bucket but I had the same problem.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you add storage admin to the SA?

Comment: @danyL what do you mean ? Can you detail your comment, plz ?

Comment: If you look at error it says SA is missing permission, so you need to go to MENU> IAM and admin and check that SA if it has the required permissions,. Try to add storage admin n test.

Comment: That missing permission is contained in role Storage Admin. That is the reason I am suggesting you to add it for a test.